# How to get a Plupload filename?

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload, plupload

I am using "plupload" to upload files then redirect to an acknowledgement page.
What I would like to do is add the filename to the url string

```
EG(www.mysite/thanks.php?file=file.jpg)
```

For someone at my level the documentation for plupload comes across as somewhat sparse and I have been unable to identify which variable/object carries the file name.

Here's where I would like to put the code

```
Uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(Up, File, Response) {
  if( (Uploader.total.uploaded + 1) == Uploader.files.length) {

    // var myfilename = !!!!!!!!!!!!!           

    window.location = 'uploaded.php?file=!!!!!!!!!';
    };
})
```

I would really appreciate some assistance with this, frankly it's driving me to distraction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(Up, File, Response) {
  if( (Uploader.total.uploaded + 1) == Uploader.files.length) {
    window.location = 'uploaded.php?file=' + encodeURIComponent(File.name);
  };
})
```

You can also check the documentation for additional options : http://www.plupload.com/plupload/docs/api/index.html#class_plupload.File.html

Comment: You are awesome :) This has given me exactly what I asked for. Many, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much sure about PHP but plupload use file as form variable for file you are trying to upload. If you just want to pass file name in url try different name may be filename instead of file.