# How can I find the new file name in plupload

Tags: javascript, php, html, plupload

I use Plupload for uploading my files. I set unique_names:true and so the files are stored with a unique file name.

But when I the event UploadComplete or FilesAdded is called the file name is still the same as on the desktop.

That's the code:

```
FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
                    for (var i in files) {
                        files[i].name = files[i].name.split('_').join(' ').trim();
                        alert('Selected files: ' + files[i].name);

           }
           },

            UploadComplete: function(up, files) {
                // Called when all files are either uploaded or failed
            for (var i in files) {
                        files[i].name = files[i].name.split('_').join(' ').trim();
                        alert('uploaded files: ' + files[i].name);

           }
            },
```

How can I find the new unique name?

Thanks

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956132/how-to-get-a-plupload-filename

Comment: No that's something else :)

Comment: ok sry..it was showing in suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

The generated unique file name is the file.id